# Use the option "establish connection in a new tab" Filezilla by default

Tags: windows-7, filezilla

Is there any way to remove this dialog box and use the option "establish connection in a new tab" by default?

[image]

I am annoyed to have this additional click to do each time I connect to an FTP server. The [feature was suggested two years ago](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=26074), I wonder whether this got implemented.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest FileZilla version there is an additional checkbox "always perform this action".

Once you chose an option as default, you can change this choice (or reset to "ask") under Edit > Settings > Interface -- Behaviour.